# How to create fat jar using sbt

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am newbie to spark programming. I want to create fat jar which include all dependency jars as well. Currently I am running spark application with following command

```
./spark-submit -class XYZ --jars dependency_1,dependency_2 main.jar
```

But I don't want each and every time to pass these dependency jar. I googled it but could not find working solution.

One of way I tried is using assembly plugin. But it's giving following error.

```
[error] Not a valid command: assembly
[error] Not a valid project ID: assembly
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: assembly
[error] assembly
[error]
```

So please any one have idea which is best way to create fat jar.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit1**--

My **build.sbt**--

```
import AssemblyKeys._

assemblySettings

name := "Update Sim Count"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.5.0-RC1"

libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.12"
```

**assembly.sbt:**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

**Edit2-**

Answer given by @Chobeat worked. Followed that blog. No need of build.scala from that blog. You can only add assembly.sbt and few lines to build.sbt. That will work for you. Thanks @Chobeat for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember to add the sbt assembly plugin to your project. It's not a default command.

Building a fat jar with Spark is a bit tricky at first but it's not black magic. And also it's the correct way to achieve what you want to do.

Follow a tutorial and you will be good:

http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/04/08/creating-uber-jar-for-spark-project-using-sbt-assembly/

Comment: I followed given link but it gives me following error when I run **sbt assembly**:---fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.253.113]: errno=Connection refused
github.com[1: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Connection refused

Thanks

Comment: Ok, they changed some things.

Restore your project as it was before and then try with the official docs. It should be enough to add the dependency in the assembly.sbt file.

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Comment: Have you removed the "dependsOn" part in your Plugins object?

Comment: I followed this official doc. It gives error posted as in question. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: Please check updated question for build.sbt and assembly.sbt

Comment: that is the IP of github. It works from my PC but you maybe have some problems with your environment. Are you trying to build your job from some kind of virtual machine/server? Because that may not have access to the internet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133341/discussion-between-digsss-and-chobeat).